# I want to display a textfield below if the checkbox is checked in flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]

If user clicks on any of the checkbox then a textformfield should be displayed below the checkbox to enter the unit configuration.

For example when user clicks on a checkbox 1BHK then a textformfield should be visible under it and if he clicks on 2 BHK then a textformfield should be visible under it and so on.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CheckBoxes extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckBoxes({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CheckBoxes> createState() => _CheckBoxesState();
}

class _CheckBoxesState extends State<CheckBoxes> {
  static List<String> selectedOptions = [];
  List<CheckboxListTile>? bhkOptions;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedOptions = [];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bhkOptions = [
      CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text('1 BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('1 BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value!) {
              selectedOptions.add('1 BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('1 BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
      CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text('2 BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('2 BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value!) {
              selectedOptions.add('2 BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('2 BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
      CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text('3 BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('3 BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value!) {
              selectedOptions.add('3 BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('3 BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
      CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text('4 BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('4 BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value!) {
              selectedOptions.add('4 BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('4 BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
      CheckboxListTile(
        title: Text('5+ BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('5+ BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value!) {
              selectedOptions.add('5+ BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('5+ BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
    ];

    return Column(
      children: bhkOptions!,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CheckboxListTile-class.html (below the headline "CheckboxListTile isn't exactly what I want") you can create a custom checkbox widget. The class `CheckBoxTile` doesn't contain properties to set a child widget below the checkbox.

The following code snippets implements a custom checkbox class `MyCustomCheckbox`. The `TextFormField` is the second item in a column and is only shown if the `value` property of `MyCustomCheckbox` isn't null. Which exactly means that the checkbox is selected. The first item of the column includes the checkbox label and the checkbox itself.

```
class MyCustomCheckbox extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCustomCheckbox({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    required this.value,
    required this.onChanged,
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16)
  });

  final Text text;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final bool value;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        onChanged(!value);
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: padding,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: text),
                Checkbox(
                  value: value,
                  onChanged: (bool? newValue) {
                    onChanged(newValue!);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            value
                //.........................................
                //HERE IS THE TextFormField WIDGET
                //.........................................
                ? TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                      labelText: 'You\'ve selected this option, please specify...',
                    )
                  )
                //SizedBox is just an empty placeholder
                : const SizedBox() 
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class CheckBoxes extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckBoxes({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CheckBoxes> createState() => _CheckBoxesState();
}

class _CheckBoxesState extends State<CheckBoxes> {
  static List<String> selectedOptions = [];
  List<MyCustomCheckbox>? bhkOptions;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedOptions = [];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bhkOptions = [
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('1 BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('1 BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value!) {
              selectedOptions.add('1 BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('1 BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('2 BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('2 BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value!) {
              selectedOptions.add('2 BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('2 BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('3 BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('3 BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value!) {
              selectedOptions.add('3 BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('3 BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('4 BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('4 BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value!) {
              selectedOptions.add('4 BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('4 BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('5+ BHK'),
        value: selectedOptions.contains('5+ BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
          setState(() {
            if (value!) {
              selectedOptions.add('5+ BHK');
            } else {
              selectedOptions.remove('5+ BHK');
            }
          });
        },
      ),
    ];

    return Column(
      children: bhkOptions!,
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

---

EDIT

You've asked in your comment how to access the value set by the checkboxes in another page.

Maybe this guide from the official flutter docs https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple
is worthwhile reading for you. At least it was for me quite helpful.

*Your widgets are organized in a widget tree*. In order to edit one variable in widget A and access this variable in a different widget B you should **declare this variable in a widget that is a common ancestor of A and B**.

Then the question arises: How to pass the info/the set handler down the widget tree to A and B. One solution passing it down using constructor parameters, another is using `InheritedWidget`s.

In the following approach I've used the provider package, which basically simplifies use of the `InheritedWidget`s.
Here, the common ancestor is the `MyApp` widget which manages its (state) variable in `MyAppState`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MyAppState(),
      child: const MaterialApp(
        title: _title,
        home: StartPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class MyAppState extends ChangeNotifier {

  //.................................
  //
  // here are the variables that must be available to more than one page and which are gonna
  // change while the app's running
  //
  //...........................................................................  
  List<String> bhkOptions = [];
  String city = 'Rome';


  bhkOptionsAdd(String s){
    bhkOptions.add(s);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bhkOptionsRemove(String s){
    bhkOptions.remove(s);
    notifyListeners();
  }

}


//from this simple start page you have access to other different pages
class StartPage extends StatelessWidget{
  const StartPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("AppBar")),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const SelectOptionsPage(),
                ));
              },
              child: Text("Options")
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const ClientPreferencesPage(),
                ));
              },
              child: Text("Client Preferences"))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}


//on this page you gonna set the checkboxes
class SelectOptionsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SelectOptionsPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Select Options')),
      body: const CheckBoxes()
    );
  }
}

//this pages uses the values which have been set in the screen with the checkboxes
class ClientPreferencesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ClientPreferencesPage();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final myAppState = Provider.of<MyAppState>(context);
    String prefers = myAppState.bhkOptions.join(", ");

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Client page")),
        body: Center(
            child: Text("Client prefers $prefers real estate in ${myAppState.city}")));
  }
}


//this widget is used in SelectOptionsPage
class CheckBoxes extends StatelessWidget {
  const CheckBoxes({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appState = Provider.of<MyAppState>(context);


    List<Widget> bhkOptions = <Widget>[
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('1 BHK'),
        value: appState.bhkOptions.contains('1 BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
            if (value!) {
              //myAppState.selectedBhkOptions
              appState.bhkOptionsAdd('1 BHK');
            } else {
              appState.bhkOptionsRemove('1 BHK');
            }
        },
      ),
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('2 BHK'),
        value: appState.bhkOptions.contains('2 BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
            if (value!) {
              appState.bhkOptionsAdd('2 BHK');
            } else {
              appState.bhkOptionsRemove('2 BHK');
            }
        },
      ),
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('3 BHK'),
        value: appState.bhkOptions.contains('3 BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
            if (value!) {
              appState.bhkOptionsAdd('3 BHK');
            } else {
              appState.bhkOptionsRemove('3 BHK');
            }
        },
      ),
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('4 BHK'),
        value: appState.bhkOptions.contains('4 BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
            if (value!) {
              appState.bhkOptionsAdd('4 BHK');
            } else {
              appState.bhkOptionsRemove('4 BHK');
            }
        },
      ),
      MyCustomCheckbox(
        text: const Text('5+ BHK'),
        value: appState.bhkOptions.contains('5+ BHK'),
        onChanged: (bool? value) {
            if (value!) {
              appState.bhkOptionsAdd('5+ BHK');
            } else {
              appState.bhkOptionsRemove('5+ BHK');
            }
        },
      ),
    ];

    return Column(
      children: bhkOptions,
    );
  }
}


//this widget is used in CheckBoxes
class MyCustomCheckbox extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCustomCheckbox({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    required this.value,
    required this.onChanged,
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 16)
  });

  final Text text;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final bool value;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        onChanged(!value);
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: padding,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(child: text),
                Checkbox(
                  value: value,
                  onChanged: (bool? newValue) {
                    onChanged(newValue!);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            value
                //.........................................
                //HERE IS THE TextFormField WIDGET
                //.........................................
                ? TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                      labelText: 'You\'ve selected this option, please specify...',
                    )
                  )
                //SizedBox is just an empty placeholder
                : const SizedBox() 
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is working absolutely fine, thanks for your help. I will store the values  by using onChanged inside the TextFormField, but later i am facing issue while i am using the value  in another page can you please help me regarding that.

Comment: For example I have stored the 1BHK data in a variable like oneBhkData = 'this is a 1 bhk good looking home'. But while i am moving to another dart file i am facing trouble accessing this variable there.

Comment: Can i know how can I get the values of each bhk configuration using textEditingController or onChanged methods, i am trying to access those values but can't find any solution !!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a custom class that implement by yourself instead of **CheckboxListTile**

```js
class CustomCheckboxItem extends StatefulWidget {

  final String title;

  const CustomCheckboxItem({super.key, required this.title});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _CustomCheckboxItemState();

}

class _CustomCheckboxItemState extends State<CustomCheckboxItem> {

  bool _isDisplayTextField = false;

  Color getColor(Set<MaterialState> states) {
    const Set<MaterialState> interactiveStates = <MaterialState>{
      MaterialState.pressed,
      MaterialState.hovered,
      MaterialState.focused,
    };
    if (states.any(interactiveStates.contains)) {
      return Colors.blue;
    }
    return Colors.red;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Text(widget.title),
            const Spacer(),
            Checkbox(
              checkColor: Colors.white,
              fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor),
              value: _isDisplayTextField,
              onChanged: (bool? value) {
                setState(() {
                  _isDisplayTextField = value ?? false;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        if (_isDisplayTextField)
          const TextField()
      ],
    );
  }

}
```